# How to detect update and insert in MS Sql 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to find the change in values in a column whenever a new row is inserted or updated in Sql Server 2008.

Comment: Why -negative????? I can't understand. I think its a valid question, in a valid forum. Otherwise the guy who answered below [ckuetbach] is posting some garbage thing in lieu of my question or Is he just doing formality of placing answers for sake of points?

Comment: I think it may be negative, because one short search with google, would have shown the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a databse trigger.

Take a look at the MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
IF OBJECT_ID ('Sales.reminder1', 'TR') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TRIGGER Sales.reminder1;
GO
CREATE TRIGGER reminder1
ON Sales.Customer
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
    [...] // Your code goes here.
GO
```